# How do I use Psycopg2's LoggingConnection?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'd like to log the queries that psycopg2 is making, but the [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html?highlight=loggingconnection#psycopg2.extras.LoggingConnection) doesn't really specify how LoggingConnection should be used.

```
import logging
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection

db_settings = {
    "user": "abcd",
    "password": "efgh",
    "host": "postgres.db",
    "database": "dev",
}

conn = LoggingConnection(**db_settings)
```

Gives an error

> LoggingConnection(**db_settings)
>   TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)

Answer (score 40):

Seems like setting the `connection_factory=LoggingConnection` works

```
import logging
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

db_settings = {
    "user": "abcd",
    "password": "efgh",
    "host": "postgres.db",
    "database": "dev",
}

conn = psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=LoggingConnection, **db_settings)
conn.initialize(logger)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example. I personally need the console output. For example, at the end of the sql statement the client prints this to STOUT: 
```
[2019-07-15 15:59:51] 1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 2 s 318 ms (execution: 2 s 279 ms, fetching: 39 ms)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use `LoggingConnection` directly, you need to provide the DSN as a [libpq connection string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) to `LoggingConnection()` - either a key/value connection string or a connection URI works:

```
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection

DSN = "postgresql://john:secret@localhost/mydb"
#DSN = "host=localhost dbname=mydb user=john password=secret"

logfile = open('db.log', 'a')

conn = LoggingConnection(DSN)
conn.initialize(logfile)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT 1')
```

However, I would probably use a connection factory like @kristi demonstrated.