# Postgresql & Psycopg2 unable to properly select data between two dates

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I created an API service that returns ticker,rate and date as JSON, But when i'm trying to select multiple parameters, it doesn't works properly like here is an example,lets say `end_at` = `2010-05-10` and `start_at` = `2010-05-15`:

---

Datebase model:

```
class Currency(Base):
   __tablename__ = "currency"
   ticker = Column(String)
   date = Column(Date)
   rates = Column(JSONB, primary_key=True)
```

Updated query code from Mike Orgenek's answer:

```
if end_at and start_at:
        currency = cursor.execute("""
        SELECT rates,date,ticker
        FROM currency
        WHERE ticker = %s
        AND date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC %s AND %s """, (base, start_at, end_at, ))
```

After printing the query for `start_at` = `2010-05-10` & `end_at` = `2010-05-15`

```
Out: 2020-07-04T09:32:30.898337+00:00 app[web.1]: b"\n        SELECT rates,date,ticker\n        FROM currency\n        WHERE ticker = 'EUR'\n        AND date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '2010-05-10' AND '2010-05-15' "
```

It doesn't recognizes my `start_at` parameter even with the right query [FULL API Output](https://fastrates.herokuapp.com/historical?start_at=2010-05-10&end_at=2010-05-15)

It includes dates older than the `start_at` like `"2010-01-28"`, `"2010-01-07"`, `"2010-04-16"`

Comment: What type is the date column? Date, datetime, other? If datetime, is it timezone aware?

Comment: @ilmarinen it's Date, i added the database model

Comment: You should be using bind parameters to protect against SQL injection attacks.  Until you get that fixed, construct your query separately from the `execute` step and examine what is actually being constructed in your query.

Comment: Should i use bind paramters in every query @MikeOrganek? Because i use f strings in my every `cursor.execute()`

Comment: Yes.  Please get into the habit as soon as you can.  I will put an example snippet for you as an answer.

Comment: Can you please add the updated, parameterized query code (python) used to create the query log?

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci  The query looks correct.  Did you get the results you expected?

Comment: Even with right query, it gives wrong result, still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please parameterize your queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks.

```
if end_at and start_at:
     currency = cursor.execute("""SELECT rates,date,ticker 
     FROM currency
     WHERE ticker = %s 
     AND date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC %s AND %s """, (base, start_at, end_at, ))
     print(cursor.query)  # <--- This should log the complete query sent to the db server
```

To diagnose the problem at hand, do something like this to see what you are sending, **but do not put your application live before changing all your `execute()` calls to the parameterized form.**

```
if end_at and start_at:
     query = f"""SELECT rates,date,ticker 
                   FROM currency
                  WHERE ticker = '{base}' 
                    AND date BETWEEN SYMMETRIC '{start_at}' AND '{end_at}' """
     print(query)
     currency = cursor.execute(query)
```

After fixing your queries to use parameters, to see what is being sent in the query to the server, use the `LoggingConnection` as a drop-in replacement for your existing `psycopg2.Connection` as lifted from [How do I use Psycopg2's LoggingConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950212/how-do-i-use-psycopg2s-loggingconnection).

```
import logging
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import LoggingConnection

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

conn=psycopg2.connect(connection_factory=LoggingConnection, database='some_database')
conn.initialize(logger)

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("select count(*) from some_table where id > %s", (1000, ))
```

With my basic config, logging goes to the console:

```
DEBUG:__main__:b'select count(*) from some_table where id > 1000'
```

Comment: Thanks, now i added queries instead of f strings everything is working but i am still unable to get the dates properly.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci Have you logged the actual statement being sent? There is an error in the first query in my answer.  I will correct it, but I think you already fixed it if it isn't crashing on you.  The key thing is getting the logged query.  Do you have access to the database server?

Comment: Yes i fixed it, it was sending string inside string. I do have access to the database server.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci  You have a couple of choices, then.  You can substitute the `LoggingConnection`, or you can enable query logging on the server:  http://www.microhowto.info/howto/log_all_queries_to_a_postgresql_server.html

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci  Sorry.  You can add `print(cursor.query)' after your execute to see what was actually sent to the server.  Can you please edit to add that in your question?

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci  You added the query string that came in the http request.  Can you please add the query that is being sent to PostgreSQL?  You can get it by putting a `print(cursor.query)` immediately after the `execute()` call.  I will update my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Ups. changed that sorry.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci  Is that the complete query?  It does not include the `end_date` criterion.  Can you please post the block that generated that query?

Comment: Yup, thats the complete query. Also added web info

Comment: Thanks for everything @Mike Organek, i didn't changed anything but it started working somehow..